# I am getting Error in Firebase In App messaging?

Tags: android, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am getting the error in Firebase In App Messaging
 `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/OkHttpDownloader;
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.injection.modules.PicassoModule.providesFiamController(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.0.5:52)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.injection.modules.PicassoModule_ProvidesFiamControllerFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.0.5:34)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.injection.modules.PicassoModule_ProvidesFiamControllerFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.0.5:11)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)`